# Google AppEngine - How To Perform a Partial Datastore Download

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I have a running GAE app that has been collecting data for a while.  I am now at the point where I need to run some basic reports on this data and would like to download a subset of the live data to my dev server.  Downloading all entities of a kind will simply be too big a data set for the dev server.

Does anyone know of a way to download a subset of entities from a particular kind?  Ideally it would be based on entity attributes like date, or client ID etc... but any method would work.  I've even tried a regular, full, download then arbitrarily killing the process when I thought I had enough data, but it seems the data is locked up in the .sql3 files generated by the bulkloader.

Comment: Why not create a handler for this, which sends (downloads) you a zip with the entities you need.

Comment: Thanks voscausa.  That's not a bad idea. I was thinking about dumping the subset into a new kind then doing a complete download of that, but I like your idea more.

Comment: Zip is very easy, but you can also use the blobstore.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like that default download/upload from/to GAE datastore utilities don't support filtering ([appcfg.py](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/uploadingdata) and bulkloader.py).

It seems reasonable to do one of two things:

- write a utility (select+export+save-to-local-file) and execute it locally accessing remotely GAE datastore in [remote api](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/remoteapi#Running_Remote_Shell) shell
- write a admin web function for select+export+zip - new url in handler + upload to GAE + call-it-using-http